# How to properly test a python function via pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Here is my code, where I would like to test `validate_yaml` function (I removed the function bodies, because they don't needed in question):

```
yaml_file_name = "env.yaml"
 
def load_yaml(file: str) -> list:
    pass


def validate_yaml(env_list: list):
    pass


def yaml_to_env(env_list: list):
    pass


env_list = load_yaml(f"{yaml_file_name}")
validate_yaml(env_list)
yaml_to_env(env_list)
```

This is my test file:

```
import pytest
import jsonschema
from yaml_to_env import load_yaml, validate_yaml


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "invalid_yaml",
    [
        (load_yaml("tests/yaml_files/invalid_workload_type.yaml")),
    ],
)
def test_yaml_env(invalid_yaml):
    with pytest.raises(jsonschema.ValidationError):
        validate_yaml(invalid_yaml)
```

My problem is that when I run `pytest` then the last three rows are executed too:

```
env_list = load_yaml(f"{yaml_file_name}")
validate_yaml(env_list)
yaml_to_env(env_list)
```

Why it is doing this? I would like to test only `validate_yaml` function and not call that three lines during `pytest`.

Thanks in advance

[EDIT1]

This is the best solution what I found so far:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    env_list = load_yaml(f"{yaml_file_name}")
    validate_yaml(env_list)
    yaml_to_env(env_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit is exactly what you need to do here.
In your previous attempt the code has been executed during `import` of your production code in the test file.
This is not an issue with pytest but rather basic module structure of python.
See this link for details:
[What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)
First point in the short answer seems to be what you did. :)